# Why is solr grouping returns zero?

Tags: asp.net, solr, grouping

I am using solrnet and I have to group my results by one field "thisfield". In grouping I should return this:

```
group=true&group.field=thisfield&group.limit=100
```

In my code I use this:

```
Grouping = new GroupingParameters()
{
    Fields = new[] { "thisfield" },
    Format = GroupingFormat.Grouped,
    Limit = 100,
},
```

But this code returns to me nothing, where is my problem? any ideas?

More info from putty:

**I need to get this:**
INFO: webapp=/solr path=/select params={sort=sequentialid+desc,exchangetimestamp+desc&indent=true&q=destination:LUKA+OR+sender:LUKA&group.limit=100&_=1401690365440&group.field=breadcrumbid&group=true&wt=xml} hits=539927 status=0 QTime=76

**I am getting this:**
INFO: webapp=/solr path=/select params={group.format=grouped&sort=sequentialid+desc,exchangetimestamp+desc&start=0&q=((((destination:LUKA))+OR+((sender:LUKA))))&group.limit=100&group.field=breadcrumbid&group=true&version=2.2&rows=15} hits=539927 status=0 QTime=76

Comment: `Limit = 100,` should be `Limit = 100` ?

Comment: No diffrents, comma is not important in last row, I can have it, or not.

Comment: Maybe you are not assigning the `Grouping` parameter to the Query? Can you post the entire `options` setup?

Comment: Options setup? Do you mean my result from logs, I posted in quetion, from putty. First result is from my Solr Admin, second is from my application.

Comment: OK I figure out, it is nothing wrong with my code, problem is with that I am returning List instead Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have anything wrong in the query.

Just mind that if you do a grouping query in SolrNet you need to read results from

> SolrQueryResults.Grouping.Values

instead of just using SolrQueryResults as a list, because the list will be empty.

Comment: Exactly, man where were you yestrday :D I was bodering with this for all day.It is true I had to return first grouping values, then groupby documents, then select key and for last select last or default. After that for pagination you have to return results.grouping[variable].matches (it returns number of all values. Thanks man :D

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem... and sorry for the delay  :)